# How to list all sites that contain a custom webpart in sharepoint online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts

I have made several web parts from SPFx and deployed it non-tenant wide. There are multiple sites that I have deployed these apps too, but not all sites contain all of them. Is there some api that I can pass in an web part id, and it will tell me every site that has that webpart deployed on it? These are all sites in the same site collection as well.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

If you just want the number of site using your webpart you can try to use the app monitor page in SharePoint Admin Center

https://[tenant]-admin.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/MonitoredApps.aspx

but if you want the exact url I think there should be a powershell for that

Comment: Yes I want a list of every site url

Comment: There is no OOB solution for but what I could suggest is using a powershell script. You may try this one out and just put an if statement for it to only records the webpart you are looking for -->  https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2015/08/find-all-web-parts-in-use-in-sharepoint-using-powershell.html

Comment: Using scripts is fine, but this is not for sharepoint online modern pages.